# jquery how to stop $.ajax when you click on a button

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

How can I stop him in the $.ajax() function when you click on this button:

```
<button class="stop">Stop</button>
```

There is any function that cause to $.ajax() stop?

Note: My $.ajax script is found in a function, for example:

```
function useajax()
{
    $.ajax(...)
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kill Ajax requests using JavaScript using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR), which has an abort method.

```
var jqXHR;
function useajax()
{
    jqXHR = $.ajax(url, data, function() { /* complete */});
}

$(".stop").click(function(){ jqXHR.abort(); });
```

Comment: my case is little more complication, because I'm using $.ajax in a function.

Comment: Not really, you just need to declare your jqXHR variable outside the scope of your function.

Comment: like this: var jqXHR = useajax(); and to abort: jqXHR.abort(); ?

Comment: Just a second, I'm checking this out.

Comment: It doesn't work from some reason. May I talk with on the stackoverflow's chat?